One-form transformation law
Suppose $V^\mu$ is a vector. Let $V_\mu$ be the corresponding one-form obtained by contracting $V$ with the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu \nu}$. Then
\begin{equation}
    V_\mu = \eta_{\mu \nu}V^\nu.
\end{equation}
I want to show that this newly obtained one-form is indeed a one-form. I know that I need to check whether $V_\mu$ satisfies the one-form transformation law given by
\begin{equation}
    V_{\mu'} = V_\mu\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\mu'}
\end{equation}
But I am not sure how to begin with this, I can't imagine this being a sophisticated computation but I am quite new to these calculations.

It only makes sense to ask this if you make use of the fact that, by definition, a contravariant vector transforms according to:
$$ V^{\mu'} = \Lambda^{\mu'}{}_{\mu}V^{\mu} $$
So that you can multiply both sides by the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\nu'\mu'}$:
$$\eta_{\nu'\mu'} V^{\mu'} =\eta_{\nu'\mu'} \Lambda^{\mu'}{}_{\mu}V^{\mu} $$
This lowers the index on the LHS to give a one form (a covariant vector), and on the RHS we can also put $V^{\mu} = \eta^{\mu\nu}V_\nu$:
$$V_{\nu'} =\eta_{\nu'\mu'} \Lambda^{\mu'}{}_{\mu}\eta^{\mu\nu} V_{\nu} $$
Now following the prescription of raising and lowering indices in $\eta_{\nu'\mu'} \Lambda^{\mu'}{}_{\mu}\eta^{\mu\nu}_{}$ we see that we get the inverse transformation, $\Lambda_{\nu'}{}^{\nu}$, so:
$$V_{\nu'} = \Lambda_{\nu'}{}^{\nu}V_\nu $$
This result is different from what you wrote, because it is always the rightmost index of the transformation that gets contracted with the vector. The closest thing you can write that would still have a similar form however is:
$$V_{\nu'} = V_\nu\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^{\nu}{}_{\nu'} $$
Because $\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^{\nu}{}_{\nu'} =  \Lambda_{\nu'}{}^{\nu}$. However there's usually no reason to express the transformation this way.
In general, note that it's very important to keep track of the placement of the indices in a tensor with more than one index. Here, $\Lambda_{\nu'}{}^{\nu}$ transforms a co-vector $V_\nu$ (one form) to the primed system while $\Lambda^{\mu'}{}_{\mu}$ transforms a contravariant vector $V^\mu$ to the primed system.

I am reading Sean Carroll's text and for some reason his inverse transformations have indcies aligned like the way I asked. All other resources use the flipped version (which you have used in your answer and honestly, that's how I think it should be.) I understand your derivation, so  thank you for the answer.

Glad to help! And, I see what you mean. Interestingly, in his own lecture notes that are free to read online here, he himself uses the more standard convention -- see equation 1.37, page 18.
